# is there a list of where the letter samech occurs with a degesh in the Chumash

Tags: torah-study, aleph-bet-letters

Is there a source that i can link to that shows all the words in the torah with a dagesh in the Samech ?

Comment: There are probably hundreds of such instances. Why would you want a list of them, and why would you think such a list already exists?

Comment: i am fascinated with a samch that has a dagesh in it

Comment: (I can't tell if you are being sarcastic or not.) What is so cool about it?

Comment: Definitely NOT sarcastic. I just see a hitherto unexplored pattern and merging with these samechs and would love b'eh to explore it further .

Comment: You might be able to search for it in an online chumash.

Answer (score 3):

סּ is what you want.

(In Python: `print(chr(1505)+chr(1468))` )

Then go to https://mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t01.htm, for example (Genesis); use CTRL+F to search within the page, paste in  סּ, including "match diacritics" (at least in Firefox), and you'll find 45 just in Genesis. (The first is 2:11, "ha**S**ovev").

Continue for the other books of Tanach, or use a script to speed it up.